# Use UIRefreshControl for UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, ios6

I saw the UIRefreshControl in iOS 6 and my question is if it is possible to refresh a WebView by pulling it down and than let it pop up like in mail?
Code I used rabih is the WebView:

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [rabih addSubview:rabih];
```

Comment: Are you sure you need it for a `UIWebView` and not a `UITableView`?

Comment: @woz Yes I want to refresh a UIWebView, called rabih, with this method.

Comment: I'm not sure the effect you're going for, but couldn't you use JavaScript for that?

Comment: @woz This is for iOS not for OSX

Comment: Just a comment: It's not really a great user experience to have the UIWebView reload with a "pull-to-refresh" gesture. These are generally useful for vertical scrollviews, in particular a `UITableView`

Answer (score 48):

This is how you can use pull down to refresh on UIWebview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   // Make webView a delegate to itself

   // I am going to add URL information
   NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.umutcankoseali.com/";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   _webView.delegate = (id)self;
   [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];

   UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
   [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   [_webView.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl]; //<- this is point to use. Add "scrollView" property.
}

-(void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {
   // Reload my data
   NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.umutcankoseali.com/";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
   [refresh endRefreshing];
}
```

Comment: +1 Wonderful and ingenious solution! Works perfectly - in fact it should work **perfectly** with anything that is a subclass of `UIScrollView`

Comment: Yup! That is also true @RazorSharp.

Answer (score 9):

In **Swift** use this,

Let's assume you wants to have pull to refresh in WebView,

So try this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addPullToRefreshToWebView()
}

func addPullToRefreshToWebView(){
    var refreshController:UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    refreshController.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 50, refreshController.bounds.size.width, refreshController.bounds.size.height) // Change position of refresh view
    refreshController.addTarget(self, action: Selector("refreshWebView:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    refreshController.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull down to refresh...")
    YourWebView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshController)

}

func refreshWebView(refresh:UIRefreshControl){
    YourWebView.reload()
    refresh.endRefreshing()
}
```

In Objective-C, I used this:

```
- (void)addPullToRefreshToWebView{
    UIColor *whiteColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIRefreshControl *refreshController = [UIRefreshControl new];
    NSString *string = @"Pull down to refresh...";
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : whiteColor };
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];
    refreshController.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, refreshController.bounds.size.width, refreshController.bounds.size.height);
    refreshController.attributedTitle = attributedString;
    [refreshController addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshWebView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [refreshController setTintColor:whiteColor];
    [self.webView.scrollView addSubview:refreshController];
}

- (void)refreshWebView:(UIRefreshControl*)refreshController{
    [self.webView reload];
    [refreshController endRefreshing];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've just added this very quickly to my code:

```
[webserver.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl]
```

So it seems that the `UIWebView` has itself a `UIScrollView` you can just attach to. Hope it's useful for you.

Comment: So could you please edit your answer to complete the question. How did you change the code?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(loadPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.webView.scrollView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
}

Answer (score 3):

I've actually tried that and got error following.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIRefreshControl may only be managed by a UITableViewController'

I could use in UIScrollView and UICollectionView though.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I don't believe it is. You actually can't use it with just any UITableView. The tableView needs to be party of a UITableViewController to be used properly.

That said, its possible you might be able to get away with sticking one above your UIWebView and controlling its frame and values manually. Things that the UITableViewController has been updated to do on its own with its refreshControl property.

Comment: I know that this is possible because I know one app which can do this.

Comment: Even if it is possible that doesn't mean you should do it. And its possible they are not using a UIRefreshControl and simple are good at copying Apple's style as has been the case many times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CKRefreshControl](https://github.com/instructure/CKRefreshControl), which you may be able to customize to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @umut-can-köseali answer to have better control of the UIRefreshControl when refresh ends:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleWebViewRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.webView.scrollView addSubview:_refreshControl]; //<- this is point to use. Add "scrollView" property.
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)_webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [_refreshControl endRefreshing];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView {
    NSString *navigatorUrl = _webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    if( navigatorUrl && ![navigatorUrl isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSString *host=_webView.request.URL.host;
        NSString *path=_webView.request.URL.path;
        [_refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on @Zaid Pathan answer but updated for Swift 4.

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

var refreshController:UIRefreshControl!
var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//Your webView initializing

    webView.scrollView.bounces = true //DONT FORGET IT!!!

    refreshController = UIRefreshControl()

    refreshController.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: refreshController.bounds.size.width, height: refreshController.bounds.size.height)
    refreshController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refreshWebView(refresh:)) , for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    refreshController.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshController)
}

@objc func refreshWebView(refresh:UIRefreshControl){
    webView.reload()
}
```

Finally, don't forget to stop reloading:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if refreshController.isRefreshing{
        refreshController.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```