# Why isn't my iOS refresh controller working?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone explain why my pull to refresh isn't working? I've called the UIRefresh controller and the "pull to refresh" animation works but the table view doesn't reload the XML data. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
  NSXMLParser *parser;
  NSMutableArray *feeds;
  NSMutableDictionary *item;
  NSMutableString *title;
  NSMutableString *link;
  NSString *element;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
  [super awakeFromNib];
}

// Paste Blog feed here
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.placeholder.xml"];
  parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
  [parser setDelegate:self];
  [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
  [parser parse];
  UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
  [refreshControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(refresh:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  refreshControl.attributedTitle =
      [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to refresh..."];
  self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
  // ... your refresh code
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.placeholder.xml"];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

  [sender endRefreshing];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell =
      [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.textLabel.text =
      [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
  return cell;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
       namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
      qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
         attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

  element = elementName;

  if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    title = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    link = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
     namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

    [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
  }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

  if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [title appendString:string];
  } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
    [link appendString:string];
  }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

  [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to define "not working." What's not working?

Comment: did u add it to the view? Is ur view controller a subclass of UITableViewController?

Answer (score 0):

The idea presented in the answer here should help: [stackoverflow.com/a/16347259/1151545](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16347259/1151545)

Basically create ur UIRefreshControl then add it as a subview to any UIScrollView.  FYI the UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView